# TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `handle.required`

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am getting an undefined error when trying to require my Mongoose Schemas in my routes file. I have created the Schema in Profile.js, and I will use in with Express in profile.js. I know there have been previous questions about this, but nothing suggested will solve it for me.

**Profile.js** (where my Schema is created)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
  handle: {
    types: String,
    required: true,
    max: 40
  },
  company: {
    type: String
  },
  website: {
    type: String
  },
  region: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  skills: {
    type: [String]
  },
  bio: {
    type: String
  },
  githubusername: {
    type: String
  },
  experience: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      company: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      to: {
        type: Date
      },
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      description: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ],
  social: {
    youtube: {
      type: String
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String
    },
    twitch: {
      type: String
    },
    telegram: {
      type: String
    },
    discord: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);
```

**profile.js** (where I require it)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');

// Load Profile Model
const Profile = require('../../models/Profile');
// Load User Model
const User = require('../../models/User');

router.get('/test', (req, res) => res.json({ msg: 'Profile Works' }));

router.get(
  '/',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const errors = {};

    Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
      .then(profile => {
        if (!profile) {
          errors.noprofile = 'There is no profile for this user';
          return res.status(404).json(errors);
        }
        res.json(profile);
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

**Error**

```
C:\Users\Razer\Desktop\MCREP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:626
    throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at `' + path +
    ^

TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `handle.required`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
    at Function.Schema.interpretAsType (C:\Users\Razer\Desktop\MCREP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:626:11)
    at Schema.path (C:\Users\Razer\Desktop\MCREP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:483:29)
    at Schema.add (C:\Users\Razer\Desktop\MCREP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:364:12)
    at Schema.add (C:\Users\Razer\Desktop\MCREP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:353:14)
    at new Schema (C:\Users\Razer\Desktop\MCREP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:88:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Razer\Desktop\MCREP\models\Profile.js:5:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Razer\Desktop\MCREP\routes\api\profile.js:7:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote **types** in

```
handle: {
    types: String,
    required: true,
    max: 40 
},
```

try to change it to **type**

Comment: Many thanks, spent ages looking but struggled to find a problem.